# Choose specific date with strptime in r

Tags: r, time-series, strptime

I have a text file dataset with headers

```
YEAR MONTH DAY value
```

which runs hourly from 1/6/2010 to 14/7/2012. I open and plot the data with the following commands:

```
data=read.table('example.txt',header=T)
time = strptime(paste(data$DAY,data$MONTH,data$YEAR,sep="-"), format="%d-%m-%Y")
plot(time,data$value)
```

However, when the data are plotted, the x axis only shows 2011 and 2012. [image]. How can I do to keep the 2011 and 2012 labels but also to add some specific month, e.g. if I want March, June & September?

I have made the data available on this link

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107215263/example.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use function `axis.POSIXct` to format and dispose of your date labels as you wish:

```
plot(time,data$value,xaxt="n") #Skip the x-axis here
axis.POSIXct(1, at=pretty(time), format="%B %Y")
```

[image]

To see all possible formats, see `?strptime`.
You can of course play with parameter `at` to place your ticks wherever you want, for instance:

```
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(time[1],time[length(time)],"3 months"), 
             format="%B %Y")
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is bit confusing at first since you are using your own sample data. Perhaps you can use OP's sample data for clarity.

Comment: Since the issue was with the x-axis design only, I didn't think it would matter for anyone (and I also didn't see that the OP upoladed his data). But here it is with the OP data.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer question directly, I would like to suggest you to use `xts` package for any timeseries analysis. It makes timeseries analysis very convenient

```
require(xts)

DF <- read.table("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107215263/example.txt", header = TRUE)
head(DF)
##   YEAR MONTH DAY    value
## 1 2010     6   1  95.3244
## 2 2010     6   2  95.3817
## 3 2010     6   3 100.1968
## 4 2010     6   4 103.8667
## 5 2010     6   5 104.5969
## 6 2010     6   6 107.2666

#Get Index for xts object which we will create in next step
DFINDEX <- ISOdate(DF$YEAR, DF$MONTH, DF$DAY)

#Create xts timeseries
DF.XTS <- .xts(x = DF$value, index = DFINDEX, tzone = "GMT")


head(DF.XTS)
##                         [,1]
## 2010-06-01 12:00:00  95.3244
## 2010-06-02 12:00:00  95.3817
## 2010-06-03 12:00:00 100.1968
## 2010-06-04 12:00:00 103.8667
## 2010-06-05 12:00:00 104.5969
## 2010-06-06 12:00:00 107.2666

#plot xts
plot(DF.XTS)
```

[image]